# Angular primeng swipe not working in iOS devices

Tags: ios, angular, carousel, primeng

There is a github issue open about this, but there is no solution apparently

https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/issues/9786

To reproduce this open https://primeng.org/carousel in iOS and try to use the gestures to move the slide multiple times

If you open it up in responsive mode in chrome / use it on Android the swiping works fine. If you try to do the same in iOS it doesn't work.

I have fixed the vertical swipe for my app which is also a problem with this component, but that doesn't solve the gestures from not working, so any recommendations would be appreciated

Comment: Please comment to the issue at GitHub. That's your best chance of getting the issue properly solved.

Comment: There is already an issue opened without any conclusion or solution, thats why i decided to ask it here

Comment: I know, it's in your question. But again, how can they fix it if you don't report it?

Comment: @JasperdeVries i just created the issue, upvote if possible 

https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/issues/12942